# Put a dynamic value from js file to html

Tags: javascript

Well, I am working on some shopping cart script where I have a js that I have included in my header as like

```
<script src="http://josscrowcroft.github.com/money.js/money.min.js"></script>
```

which is constantly updating the value of USD EUR etc.. and the function is to call the script is

```
fx.convert(1, {from: 'EUR', to: 'USD'})
```

Now my question is I need the value of USD which will be converted from EUR to show the customers both USD & EUR price which is in

as like

```
<div><h3>Product price 100 EUR or (USD value here) USD.</h3></div>
```

So how can I put the usd value there... ?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Creating_and_modifying_HTML

Comment: Please show more of your code

Comment: http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/ 
you can go there and may know what I am trying to say..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you aren't reading all of the documentation. Most of what I'm going to comment is literally taken from the link you sourced.

You need to have access to the conversion rates. He offers the following as an example:

```
fx.rates = {
  "EUR" : 0.745101,
  "GBP" : 0.647710, 
  "HKD" : 7.781919,
  "USD" : 1,        
}
```

Then, you can do the following. Change your html to the following:

```
<div><h3>Product price 100 EUR or (<span class="dollar"></span>) USD.</h3></div>
```

And then include jquery and add the following in a script tag.

```
 fx.settings = { from: "USD", to: "GBP" };
 dollar = fx.convert(100);
 $('.dollar').text(dollar);
```

Nice find, I could use something like this.

Comment: so does the money.min.js file constantly updating the rate from stock exchange server ? or I have to put it manually every day ? 


I have also seen they have offered http://openexchangerates.org/ but they charges for api I guess.. so I wanted to use their own .JS file which will update my value constantly like http://josscrowcroft.github.io/money.js/

Comment: You need to either find a free api (if there is one), buy one, or update manually.